# What is the return value for the x button in VBScript?

Tags: vbscript

What is the return value for the big red "X" button commonly found in dialog boxes like MsgBox? That is commonly used for closing out of the program.

So, how can I call upon the x button in VBScript?

Comment: What is the "x button"? The close thingy in the upper right of the dialog box (if there is such a thing)? This is one of the very few cases where [a screenshot would be appropriate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/). The OP has left the building (*"Last seen more than 4 years ago"*). Perhaps someone else can provide a screenshot? A link to such an image here in comments would be acceptable (it *will* be picked up).

Comment: It may or may not look like [this dialog box](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-msgbox/). Or [this one](https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/yes-no-message-box/#VBA_MsgBox_Function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends. After reading the docs for [MsgBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfw6660x%28v=vs.84%29.aspx), [InputBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3yfdhzk5%28v=vs.84%29.aspx), and [Popup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x83z1d9f%28v=vs.84%29.aspx), you need to experiment/test.

The return value of MsgBox after clicking X depends on the buttons in the dialog:

```
>> WScript.Echo MsgBox("no cancel, X returns 1 (ok)")
>> WScript.Echo MsgBox("with cancel, X returns 2 (cancel)", vbOkCancel)
>>
1
2
```

I **think**, that Popup works similarly; you should test carefully.

InputBox returns Empty if you press X or Cancel:

```
>> WScript.Echo TypeName(InputBox("just X me"))
>>
Empty
```