# How do I check if a button is pressed in a VBScript 'MsgBox'?

Tags: vbscript, msgbox

How do I **check** if I click on a button in a *[MsgBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/msgbox-function)*?

```
x = msgbox("Test", 0+16, "Test")
```

I meant ***check***, not how to make a message box!

Comment: Please check the return values of a [MsgBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/msgbox-function)

Comment: Where does this "`0+16`" come from? Why is it necessary?

Comment: That duplicate is a ***very*** poor choice. That question is ill-defined. It is not at all clear what the actual question is. There must be a much better (canonical) question somewhere.

Comment: A starting point is (but it is still a low-scored question): *[What is the return value for the x button in VBScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26126165/what-is-the-return-value-for-the-x-button-in-vbscript)*

Comment: Perhaps "`0+16`" is a mistyped/retyped version of "`0x16`"? Or an original with only ***one*** bit set (that could make sense for a bit-coded value), `0x10` that was attempted converted to decimal (16), but incomplete, still leaving the `0x` in? Alternatively, `0x16`, has three bits set. Does that correspond to something sensible? According to the mentioned documentation page, decimal 16 correspond to `vbCritical`. hex 0x16 corresponds to `vbCritical` + an undefined (the lower three or four bits do not appear to be bit coded).

Comment: No, `0` is `vbOKOnly` by itself. So 0+16 is trying to express `vbOKOnly` + `vbCritical`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
x = msgbox("Test", 0+16, "Test")

if x = number then
    msgbox("Hello, World!")
end if
```

instead of the "number" in the *if* statement, write the number corresponding with the button that you want to check if pressed. Here are the numbers that you can write:

1 - ok; 2 - cancel; 3 - abort; 4 - retry; 5 - ignore; 6 - yes; 7 - no

Comment: There is no excuse to not use the named constants as they are built into VBScript as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22644915/692942) 8 years ago. - See [`MsgBox` Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/sfw6660x(v=vs.84)).

Answer (score 0):

- You should learn VBScript programming from the ground up.
- [VBScript Basics, Part 1 | Message Box - Numbers (MsgBox)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NwIOuZZqolE&list=PL72Es31dJnK6-ZFXXHFurNwJ6QtWPtxbz&index=1)
- [VBScript Basics, Part 2 | Message Box - Constants (MsgBox)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ml99eRt9jSs&list=PL72Es31dJnK6-ZFXXHFurNwJ6QtWPtxbz&index=3)
- [VBScript Basics, Part 3 | If - ElseIf - Else - Then Statements](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zV_tvU1ye4s&list=PL72Es31dJnK6-ZFXXHFurNwJ6QtWPtxbz&index=3)
- [All Vbscript Tutorial Playlist](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PL72Es31dJnK6-ZFXXHFurNwJ6QtWPtxbz)

---

Here is an example:

```
 Dim AnswerQuestion, Msg, Title
 Title = "Answer the question?"
 Msg = "Do you like cookies??" & Vbcr &_
     "If yes, then click the [YES] button " & Vbcr &_
     "If not, then click the [NO] button"

 AnswerQuestion = MsgBox(Msg, VbYesNo + VbQuestion, Title)
 If AnswerQuestion = VbYes Then
     MsgBox "You clicked on the OK button. Good, you're off the hook!", vbInformation, Title
 Else
     MsgBox "You clicked on the No button! and you're going to jail!", VbCritical, Title
 End if
```

Comment: It's [been covered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22644032/vbscript-vbs-how-do-you) over 8 years ago. The question has been flagged as a duplicate and still you ignore it.